# auth is returned as none when trying to log in user when signing up

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am trying to solve the use case where when user signs up then the user is automatically logged in and return the token of that user so that i can that token in cookies from frontend. However, I get issue `"Email already registered"`. when i debug my code using pdb, i found that `auth = authenticate(username=email, password=password)` is returning None.

How can I authenticate user during signup and pass token of that user?

Here is how i am doing

```
class Register(graphene.Mutation):
    '''
        Mutation to register a user
    '''
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        password_repeat = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)
    email = graphene.String()

    def mutate(self, info, email, password, password_repeat):
        if password == password_repeat:
            try:
                serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data={
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password,
                    'is_active': False
                })
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    user = serializer.save()
                    auth = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
                    import pdb
                    pdb.set_trace()
                    # login user and pass the token
                    login(info.context, auth)
                    return Register(success=bool(user.id), email=user.email)
                else:
                    print("error", serializer.errors)
            except Exception:
                errors = ["email", "Email already registered"]
                return Register(success=False, errors=errors)
            errors = ["password", "Passwords don't match."]
            return Register(success=False, errors=errors)


class Login(graphene.Mutation):
    """
    Mutation to login a user
    """
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)
    token = graphene.String()
    user = graphene.Field(UserQuery)

    def mutate(self, info, email, password):
        user = {'email': email, 'password': password}
        serializer = JSONWebTokenSerializer(data=user)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            token = serializer.object['token']
            user = serializer.object['user']
            print('user', user)
            return Login(success=True, user=user, token=token)
        else:
            print("serializers errors", serializer.errors)
            return Login(
                success=False,
                token=None,
                errors=['email', 'Unable to login with provided credentials.']
            )
```

RegistrationSerializer

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'is_active', 'password', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated_data", validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

I am using graphql instead of REST API and I am using graphene-django for graphql.

Comment: What is RegistrationSerializer? Does it hash the password? What auth backend are you using?

Comment: I am using 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' as auth backend. Regarding serializer, i think i should update in the question.